# Im refactoring some code in JS and i need to su the values within this array, populated with characters, booleans ,numbers, objects, and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

[image]

I tried using map but it didnt work

Comment: Can you include the code as a text, instead of the image?

Comment: refactoring how? what kind of  result do you expect ?

Comment: Share the code you'd like us to refactor please - and how would you like the booleans and objects to be summed? Please edit your question to make it more understandable and answerable.

Comment: @MisterJojo thank you, i'll do

Answer (score 2):

Use a "[reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)" on a "[flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to infinity" array while parsing values(if required) inside the reducer:

PS: But if you don't want to parse "Strings" (e.g, '3') then you can modify accordingly to exclude them in the reducer function

```js
let arrayToSum = [1,2,'3',[45,'76',32,[4,78,0,'-45']],3,[[true, false, 23, 45, [[[25,67,1,-687,34,[[[[45,52,100,[[[33,25]]]],0.5]],3.45]]],78,2]]],[[0.05,'23.3',[45,32,'B','2', '45']], {}]];

const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => {
  let parsedNumber = isNaN(parseInt(currentValue)) ? 
                      0 : parseInt(currentValue);
  return (accumulator + parsedNumber);
};

console.log(arrayToSum.flat(Infinity).reduce(reducer));
```

Comment: PS: I used image processing to extract the input array the author had mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you want to sum all the numbers (not including the string representation of them, e.g. '76' is not considered in the sum), here it is a step by step of how handle this:

```js
const arrayToSum = [1,2,'3', [4], {}, false, true];
// [1,2,'3',[4],{},false,true]

const flatArray = arrayToSum.flat();
// [1,2,'3',4,{},false,true]

const numbers = flatArray.filter(item => parseInt(item) === item);
// [1,2,4]

const sum = numbers.reduce((number, total) => number + total);
// 7

// or in one line
const sum = arrayToSum
  .flat()
  .filter(item => parseInt(item) === item)
  .reduce((number, total) => number + total)
```

Comment: we can avoid a filter and move the parse logic to reducer function - saves us an unwanted traversal. cheers !